# How to swap 2 button positions in Kotlin programatically by preference?

Tags: android, kotlin, button

So, I have 2 buttons and I wanna swap them by using a preference but Yeah, I can't make them switch properly

Here is my code for preference

```
    // In MainActivity.kt

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val shouldFlipButtonPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("buttonpositions", false)
        if (isButtonPositionFlipped != shouldFlipButtonPosition) {
            isButtonPositionFlipped = shouldFlipButtonPosition
            val cleanBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cleanBtn)
            val analyzeBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.analyzeBtn)
            if (isButtonPositionFlipped) {

                // Buttons swaped.

            } else {

               // Buttons back to normal.

            }
        }
```

I tried again to make them swap but I got some ugly results like this:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val shouldFlipButtonPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("buttonpositions", false)
        if (isButtonPositionFlipped != shouldFlipButtonPosition) {
            isButtonPositionFlipped = shouldFlipButtonPosition
            val cleanBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cleanBtn)
            val analyzeBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.analyzeBtn)
            if (isButtonPositionFlipped) {
                val posX = cleanBtn.x
                val posY = cleanBtn.y
                analyzeBtn.x = posX
                analyzeBtn.y = posY
            } else {
                cleanBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                analyzeBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val shouldFlipButtonPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("buttonpositions", false)
        if (isButtonPositionFlipped != shouldFlipButtonPosition) {
            isButtonPositionFlipped = shouldFlipButtonPosition
            val cleanBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cleanBtn)
            val analyzeBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.analyzeBtn)
            if (isButtonPositionFlipped) {
                cleanBtn.setPadding(640, 0, 0, 0)
                analyzeBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 640, 0)
            } else {
                cleanBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                analyzeBtn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to mention I tried to use `set.Margins` but isn't working

How can I swap them by using this method?

Comment: not everyone has english as a first language, please don't add all this irrelevant text to your question, it's really terrible, this isn't a conversation. focus on the problem (the current problem) and don't add anything more than that

Comment: My bad. I'll be more focused on the problem next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're in a LinearLayout and they're the only two children views of that LinearLayout, you can reverse the order of the children like this:

```
findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.theParentLinearLayout).apply {
    val children = children.toList()
    removeAllViews()
    for (child in children.asReversed()) {
        addView(child)
    }
}
```

If they need different sized margins, you can swap their layout params too:

```
findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.theParentLinearLayout).apply {
    val children = children.toList()
    children[0].layoutParams = children[1].layoutParams
        .also { children[1].layoutParams = children[0].layoutParams }
    removeAllViews()
    for (child in children.asReversed()) {
        addView(child)
    }
}
```

If there are more than two children views, you can search for and swap them in a mutable list before adding them all back to the parent.

```
findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.theParentLinearLayout).apply {
    val children = children.toMutableList()
    val buttonAIndex = children.indexOf(findViewById(R.id.buttonA))
    val buttonBIndex = children.indexOf(findViewById(R.id.buttonB))
    children[buttonAIndex] = children[buttonBIndex]
        .also { children[buttonBIndex] = children[buttonAIndex] }
    children[buttonAIndex].layoutParams = children[buttonBIndex].layoutParams
        .also { children[buttonBIndex].layoutParams = children[buttonAIndex].layoutParams }
    removeAllViews()
    for (child in children) {
        addView(child)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use RelativeLayout(or ConstraintLayout):

```
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val cleanBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cleanBtn);
        val analyzeBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.analyzeBtn);
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val shouldFlipButtonPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("buttonpositions", false)
        var isButtonPositionFlipped = true;
        if (isButtonPositionFlipped != shouldFlipButtonPosition) {
            isButtonPositionFlipped = shouldFlipButtonPosition;
            (cleanBtn.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).leftMargin =
                dipToPixels(this, 100f);//100dp?
            (analyzeBtn.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).leftMargin = 0;
        } else {
            (cleanBtn.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).leftMargin = 0;
            (analyzeBtn.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).leftMargin =
                dipToPixels(this, 100f);//100dp?
        }
    }

    private fun dipToPixels(context: Context, dipValue: Float): Int {
        val metrics: DisplayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, metrics).toInt()
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cleanBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="111"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/analyzeBtn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="222"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: WoW. Thanks Currently I use Linear Layout soni guess I have to remake it.

Comment: It would be easier with LinearLayout because then you could just swap the two views order as children. This code requires both buttons to be the same width, or you’ll have to do some measuring of them after laying them out to get the right amount of margin.